# Using RTOS in library for ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, rtos

I am not new to programming for Arduino and the likes. But with ESP32 having 2 cores I wanted to make use of RTOS. I did this easily in the main source file (I use platformio to program). I would like to make libraries using this, but my programming background is VB, C#, and java..so I think I lack some understanding of how c and c++ sees libraries. I just want to start with a library that can do a blink sketch to try to understand how to do this in a library. I get reference errors when I try and would appreciate if someone can provide a library with this simple task so I can understand it better.

Comment: Not sure what you want, you don't need a library for blinking LED sketch. There is an [blinking_example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/get-started/blink/main/blink_example_main.c) available. If this is not what you want, please update you post to elaborate the problem you are facing and provide the code and the "reference errors" that you mentioned.

Comment: @hcheung I am not after that sketch it is just that I have a few things I want to run on it's own threat and I cannot seem to figure out how to make them work outside the main file, such as a separate library. A blinking led I figured was a simple example of what I wanted to do. Really it is going to be sensor data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, as Arduino on ESP32 is running on ESP-IDF which, in turn, is already running on FreeRTOS: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v5.0.1/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html

To learn more about FreeRTOS I recommend that you start with their excellent book/tutorial [Mastering the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel - a Hands On Tutorial Guide](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf)